# CTE with blank expressions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, common-table-expression

I am building a fairly large set of tabulated data. In this data I have employees and their receptive totals against company overall totals. I am having a problem in that I am using CTEs and one of my expressions counts for the number of a particular item. The count returns nothing and by including this expression in the final query makes the whole result set blank. I'm sure I'm missing something simple here:

```
...
COMPANY_TOTAL_A(A) AS
(
SELECT NVL(COUNT(ITEM),0)
FROM COMPANY_TOTALS_FINAL
WHERE ITEM = 'A'
GROUP BY ITEM
),
...
```

This query returns nothing and when I use it in my final query the whole result set is blank. If I exclude it then I get all the rows I expect back. It looks like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.ID,
C.NAME,
P.LOCATION,
...
NVL(T.A, 0)
...
FROM COMPANY C
INNER JOIN PLACE P
ON P.P_ID = C.P_ID,
...
COMPANY_TOTAL_A T;
```

As tthis value is relevant to all employees I expected it to just return the company total for when item is in class `A`. Even if that is 0 I thought 0 would be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping by the same column you are counting on is useless. You want a simple:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM company_totals_final
WHERE item = 'A'
```

`count(item)` counts all rows where item is not null, but the condition will `ITEM = 'A'` will already remove those rows anyway. So it's also not needed.